# What's the name of this serif font from Art Basel?

Tags: font-identification

Seems to be a very modern font. No identifier-service I found delivered a result.

[Source](http://jrp-ringier.com/pages/index.php?id_r=4&id_t=&id_p=8&id_b=2613)

[image]
[image]

I tried MyFonts WhatTheFont and several other services I found on Google, always without success.

Here are the WhatTheFont [results](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=Y&ch%5B1%5D=E&ch%5B2%5D=4&ch%5B3%5D=A&ch%5B4%5D=4&ch%5B5%5D=R&session=00002c65568eaccf0003a832000006232&x=76&y=40)

Comment: I started to close your question because we do require where you've tried to find the font.  I did see you mention that in a comment under an answer so I have made an edit to your question.  In the future please follow [What are the requirements for font identification questions?](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions).  Also, welcome to the site, hope to see you around.

Answer (score 7):

This font is [Genath](http://optimo.ch/typefaces_Genath_Display.html), designed by François Rappo.

[image]

The book was designed by [Gavillet & Rust](http://www.gavillet-rust.com/) who co-founded of the font foundry [Optimo](http://optimo.ch/home.html) along with François Rappo. A cruise by Optimo's [twitter](https://twitter.com/optimofoundry) account turned up this gem of a clue:

[image]

Ding ding ding! We have a winner!

Comment: Good find! +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Didone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didone_(typography)) of some sorts ([Bodoni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodoni) being one of the more popular ones).

That doesn't narrow it down much, as there are many, many didones out there. And many of them are used for things like publication mast heads and luxury product branding--both of which are not uncommon to have commissioned custom typefaces. As such, this may very well be a custom typeface just for Art Basel.

That said, it appears the book was designed by [Gavillet & Rust](http://www.gavillet-rust.com/). Maybe shoot them an email and ask the source directly!

If you continue hunting, I'd focus on the E and the M as they both stand out to me as rather unique amongst didones (the M with the curved stems and the E with the thing 'T' crossbar and triangular serifs).

Answer (score 0):

Using the [WhatTheFont tool](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), I got [New Caslon SB](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/efscangraphic/new-caslon-sb/medium/)

[image: New Caslon SB]

and [Velino Display](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/dstype/velino-display/medium/).

[image]

While they're not an **exact** match, they're pretty close (my heart is with the latter, though).

Comment: Yes, I tried MyFonts WhatTheFont and several other services I found on Google, always without success.

Comment: Here the WhatTheFont results: https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=Y&ch%5B1%5D=E&ch%5B2%5D=4&ch%5B3%5D=A&ch%5B4%5D=4&ch%5B5%5D=R&session=00002c65568eaccf0003a832000006232&x=76&y=40

Comment: Did you take a look at the fonts I linked to?

Comment: Cool, thank you, yes close matches, but I need the exact one :-(

Comment: It might a modified font, so an exact match would be impossible to find.

Comment: I don't think that is a modified font as it is only used sparely in the book and I think it's unlikely that they designed the font exclusively for that.

Comment: Could it not be custom? That's a magazine right?

Answer (score 0):

It's rather like [EF Walbaum](http://www.identifont.com/find?similar=EF+Walbaum&q=Go), although it's not identical; the serifs on E N and T differ but C and S are very similar:

[image]

Comment: True, here is the book I found it in http://jrp-ringier.com/pages/index.php?id_r=4&id_t=&id_p=8&id_b=2613